Is it possible to use FIML in a zero-inflated poisson regression in R?
I can only find codes for FIML using SEM, but is it also possible to use it with a zero-inflated poission analysis?
poisson2 <- glm(VariableY ~ VariableX1 + 
                  VariableX2 + VariableX3 + VariableX1:VariableX2 + VariableX1:VariableX3, family = "poisson", data = data) 

Error in glm.control(missing = "fiml") : 
  unused argument (missing = "fiml")

